# Can I POST an image to my rails app from another domain using jQuery AJAX?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

How do I write my create action in a controller to accept data from another server?

Is this possible with JSONP?  What about same origin policy?

I only need to worry about HTML5 compliant browsers.  Thanks!

```
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://pinky.local:3000/items',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data) {
                 console.log(data)
                    },
            processData: false,
            data: "{\"item\":{\"name\":\"foobar\"}}"
        })
```

Controller

```
def create
  @item = Item.new(params[:item])
end
```

ERROR: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://pinky.local:3000/items. Origin http://foo.local is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: It sounds like you're confusing server-side and client-side concepts. JSONP lets you `get` across domains using XMLHttpRequest. The same-origin policy is a restriction on XHR. Your server does not/should not care about where a POST comes from, and has no conception of a "same-origin policy."

Comment: I don't understand why I'm getting an error then.

Comment: Are you ajax-posting to the server that the page is running on, or not? If not, then the same-origin policy **will** block this, in which case you need to use your server as a proxy for the post.

Comment: No, I am posting from another domain/server.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $(function() {
         $('a').click(function(e){
           $.ajax({
             data: "{\"item\":{\"name\":\"foobar\"}}",
             type:'POST',
             url:'http://localhost:3000/items/upload',
             success: function(response) {
               alert('Successfully sent data!'); 
             },
             error: function(event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
             }
           });
          });
        });
    </script>
```

**match '/items/upload' => "items#upload", :conditions => { :method => :options }**

```
  def upload
        #Needs these headers for the cross-domain ajax
        headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
        headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'x-requested-with'
        if request.post?
          @item = Item.new(params[:item])
          @item.pic = data
          @item.save!
        end
        render :text => 'success'
      end
```